# How to add the routeparams between angularjs and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, routes, routeparams

I have successfully added route parameters in angular js and PHP files.
But I need to add the URL parameter for one file. I added that. But it showing an error.

I attached the code below

```
var mainbread = angular.module('mainbread', ['ngSanitize', 'ui-notification','ngRoute', 'ngStorage', 
'angular.filter', 'moment-picker', 'ngMaterial', '720kb.socialshare'])
mainbread.config(function (NotificationProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    NotificationProvider.setOptions({
        delay: 5000,
        startTop: 40,
        startRight: 40,
        verticalSpacing: 20,
        horizontalSpacing: 20,
        positionX: 'right',
        positionY: 'top'
    }),       
$routeProvider
     .when("/", {
         templateUrl : "/home.php",
         controller: "maincontrol"
     })
    .when("/donate", {
        templateUrl : "/donate.php",
        controller: "maincontrol"
    })
    .when("/donate/:raiser", {
        templateUrl : "/donate.php",
        controller: "donatectrl"
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl : "/about.php",
        controller: "maincontrol"        
    })
    .when("/blog", {
        templateUrl : "/blog.php",
        controller: "maincontrol"        
    })
    .when("/contact", {
        templateUrl : "/contact.php",
        controller: "maincontrol"
    })
    .when("/terms", {
        templateUrl : "/terms.php",
        controller: "maincontrol"
    })
    .when("/policy", {
        templateUrl : "/policy.php",
        controller: "maincontrol"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
// 'use strict';
mainbread.controller('maincontrol', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', 'Notification', '$compile', '$window', '$rootScope', '$location', '$mdDialog',
    function ($scope, $filter, $http, Notification, $compile, $window, $rootScope, $location, $mdDialog) {
    }]);

    mainbread.controller('donatectrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', 'Notification', '$compile', '$window', '$rootScope', '$location', '$mdDialog','$routeParams',
    function ($scope, $filter, $http, Notification, $compile, $window, $rootScope, $location, $mdDialog,$routeParams) {
        $scope.raiser = $routeParams.raiser;
        alert("$scope.raiser");
    }]);
```

In the above code, I added the route params "**raiser**".
When I use some parameters in URL like **domain/donate/myid**, the URL consider **donate** as a directory.
So the error shows like below
[image: Error]

I also write **.htaccess** for this. Attached the code below. Is any wrong with that?

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

DirectoryIndex main.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

How can I solve this ?.give help in this

Answer (score 0):

I understand it completely.
A PHP page will run first. Then only angular js. So we can't get the values from angular js to PHP in that situation.
Instead of that, I used API for that. Now problem solved